# Easiest way to move multiple methods from header ".h" file to implementaion ".cpp" file

Tags: c++, automated-refactoring

I often start development of a C++ class by keeping everything in the *.h* header file. At some point, I want to move most methods from the header file into the implementation *.cpp* file.

What is the easiest/automated way to do such a move? Does anyone know of a script or a tool?

I am using Eclipse Juno CDT, which has the [Toggle Function Definition](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_toggle.htm) refactoring feature. However, this feature does only 1 function at a time and requires two complete function highlights and two shortcut key presses per function. Also, it is noticeably slow, and this wouldn't be as big of an issue if it could do a bunch of functions at once.

Comment: `<Ctrl> + <X>, <Ctrl> + <V>`

Comment: The easiest way is to _not put them in the header in the first place_!

Comment: Can you create a macro to perform the instructions in your third paragraph?

Comment: I hope some readers *do* have a useful answer to this.  It's not as trivial as cut/paste, but it *is* mindless busywork.  And I know of tools that do exactly this, but not for Eclipse.

Comment: do a c&p, and then a little bit of regexp magic to remove the method bodies in the `.h`, and add the 'class space' qualifier in the `.cpp`.

Comment: @Query I don't think Eclipse has powerful macro capabilities like Emacs/Vi. This Eclipse feature is not trivial: you have to select just the function and nothing else, refactor to make it inline, then select the new inlined version at the bottom of the file, and refactor to move it to the ".cpp" file. The double manual selection makes it as slow as a simple manual copy and paste. Also, the refactoring doesn't always work. Sometimes it throws an error even when the code compiles correctly.

Comment: Refactorings for C++: moving methods to source file and back to the header - http://www.skorkin.com/2011/07/refactorings-for-c-moving-methods-to-source-file-and-back-to-the-header/

Comment: So what are the criteria for moving "most" methods from the .h file to the .cpp file?  Any and all methods in the class declaration? What about inlines? You want to leave behind a method declaration? Data members... which ones? *Which* .cpp file?  What about includes needed by the method body, but not needed by other .h file elements that are not moved? What if the declaration is embedded in a conditional? If part is embedded?  This might be more complex than just a keyboard macro.

Comment: @Drew Dormann What tool (that is not for Eclipse)? In your 4-years-ago comment, did you mean Resharper?  It can only move one-by-one.  Are there any better tools?